# Need to update the DB table automatically

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2005

I am using Excel sheet for reading the values and updating in DB. I have two questions:

1. How to avoid duplicates in DB table when same value is added in Excel Sheet?
2. If a new value/s is updated in Excel sheet, I will run the java source console once again and execute the query in the DB to see the results. But I don't want that... Instead of that, if any values is modified/updated in Excel sheet, it should automatically reflect in DB Table.

Is there any ways to do that?

Comment: Are you using Excel as a CRUD frontend?

Comment: Hi thomas,
No i am not using CRUD frontend.. Jus need to update the modified data in excel sheet to DB without appending the already existed value

Comment: I'd suggest not directly tying the Excel file to the database since it would a) require the database to be reachable by the excel - i.e. what if the excel is sent somewhere? - and b) might still require a user action to trigger the update (you'd not want the update to happen immidiately, would you?). Thus I'd just use the excel file as input for a program that updates the database from it and can perform additional checks, conversions etc. .

Answer (score 0):

1) to avoid duplicates in DB table, just make the column unique. Non-unique updates/inserts will just fail.

```
create table mytable (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(255) unique not null
);
```

2) if you want it to reflect directly in the DB, I suggest you just link MS Access directly to the DB table. It looks very much like Excel and is probably what you want.
You can also try a free Access like OpenOffice.org Base.